# How to create alias during index creation in Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

My class looks like that:

```java
@Document(indexName = "a")
@Mapping(mappingPath = "mapping-a.json")
public class A {

    @Id
    private String id;
```

What I would like to do is to instead of just creating and using index `a` here I would like to create some index and use alias (with some config) for it. Like in ES documentation example from [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-add-alias.html#alias-index-creation):

[image]

The only solution that I can think of is to just "manually" create index on startup, but I was hoping for some built in feature in Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

We don't support creating an alias on index creation yet, you'd like to open an issue in [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAES/issues/) for that.

Your case looks like you should create an index template (available since Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.1) for the index name pattern *logs_2030** that defines the alias, no need to specify this on the entity class.

Comment: Thx, I didn't knew this feature of ES and Spring Data ES. It looks like it would be nice to have this alias in index creation. With my limited understanding it seems that using index template is a little bit of workaround - but maybe I just connect the dots longer way :)